# How can I call a text from a random switch case?

Tags: xcode, text, switch-statement

```
- (IBAction)postToTwitter:(id)sender {
 if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{

SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController

composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

[tweetSheet setInitialText:@"This is the text which should be called from switch case"];

 [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

 }

}
```

////And here is my switch case just to give an idea to you

```
-(IBAction) random {
int text = arc4random() % 3;
switch (text) {

    case 0:

 textview.text = @"Text example 1";

        break;

    case 1:

        textview.text = @"Text example 2";

        break;

    case 2:

        textview.text = @"Text example 3";

        break;

default:

        break;

   }

}
```

Just I want to input Text example 1, Text example 2 and Text example 3 to my Twit content while my switch case is changing.
Help please!!! :'(

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace it with

```
[controller setInitialText:textview.text];
```